# Using variables in the values-form in multiple-value-bind

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to implement a function `read-from-whole-string` in lisp, where it uses the inbuilt function `read-from-string`.

---

### About `read-from-string`

[read-from-string](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_fro.htm) is used to read an object from a string which can be specified using the keywords `:start`,`:end` etc. It returns two values, the object and the position of the next element, which wasn't read. I plan to use this value.

---

### The plan

The plan is to use the second value returned from the `read-from-string` function, again on itself to insert the value of the keyword `:start`. But the problem comes with the function [multiple-value-bind](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_multip.htm). We can't:

1. Initialize a variable in `multiple-value-bind`.
2. Use a variable just defined into the `values-form`.

To be specific, I want to:

```
(multiple-value-bind (x (y 0))
         (read-from-string str :Start y)
         y)
```

Any other clean method is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a string stream, read and discard an object, and then read again:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (with-input-from-string (*standard-input* "1 2") (read) (read))
2
```

To read all the elements from the input string we can loop on `read` and use a unique value to detect EOF, rather than have it throw an error:

```
(with-input-from-string (s "1 2 3 4")
  (loop with eof = '#:eof
        for item = (read s nil eof)
        until (eq item eof)
        collecting item))
-> (1 2 3 4)
```

To extract all the objects in a string, we could also wrap it in parentheses and use a single application of `read-from-string`:

```
(read-from-string (format nil "(~a)" "1 2 3 4"))
-> (1 2 3 4); 11
```

The danger there is the lack of diagnosis for situations when the string contains this sort of problem: `"a b ) c d"`.  We can check for that situation by comparing the returned length to the string length to make sure all of it was read, and issue some generic diagnostic if it wasn't.

```
(defun read-whole-string (str)
  (let ((par-str (format nil "(~a)" str)))
    (multiple-value-bind (obj len) (read-from-string par-str)
      (if (eql len (length par-str))
        obj
        (error "read-whole-string: ~a is malformed at position ~s"
               str (- len 2))))))
```

Comment: But, this `(read)` will only read an object(here "1" , and then "2"). I want to read the whole string. That is, read "1 2", to return `(1 2)`. This can't be done by `with-input-from-string`.

Comment: Your question could be improved with input and output pairs.    Reading the list `(1 2)` from the string `"1 2"` can be done, for example, by turning it into `"(1 2)"` and using `read-from-string`.

Answer (score 3):

```
CL-USER 118 > (let ((string "10 2 300 foo \"bar\""))
                (loop with pos and value
                      for start = 0 then pos
                      do (setf (values value pos)
                               (read-from-string string nil string :start start))
                      while (not (eq value string))
                      collect value))
(10 2 300 FOO "bar")

CL-USER 120 > (let ((string "10 2 300 foo \"bar\""))
                (loop for start = 0 then pos
                      for (value pos) = (multiple-value-list
                                         (read-from-string string nil string
                                                           :start start))
                      while (not (eq value string))
                      collect value))
(10 2 300 FOO "bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method for implementing the function `read-from-whole-string` , which might not be too clean is:

```
(defun read-from-whole-string (str)
  (loop 
    collect (multiple-value-bind (x y)
                (read-from-string str)
              (setf str (delete-if #'atom str :start 0 :end (if (= (length str) y)
                                                                y
                                                               (1- y))))
              x)
    until (zerop (length str))
        ))
```

Comment: DELETE-IF ATOM for a string makes no sense.